# Using react callback ref with forwarded ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a Checkbox react component that has to support the indeterminate state, but I'm updating our components to forward refs properly. The checkbox component already uses a callback ref internally to set the indeterminate property. Here's the original component (simplified):

```js
export type ICheckboxProps = {
  checked?: boolean
  indeterminate?: boolean
} & React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>

export const Checkbox: React.FC<ICheckboxProps> = props => {
  const { checked = false, ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={checked}
      ref={ref => {
        if (ref) {
          ref.indeterminate = !checked ? indeterminate! : false;
        }
      }}
      {...rest}
    />
  )
}
```

Now, since this is a UI library, I'm trying to forward a ref as well. But that clashes with the callback ref - now I have two separate refs. Additionally, the *forwarded* ref could be a callback ref. So I can't even access the instance there to set the indeterminate property. I've tried a bunch of stuff, but no matter what I do typescript's helpful red underlines tell me that I'm wrong.

How do I both apply the forwarded ref to the input and set the indeterminate property on the input?

Here's it most of the way but there's an issue noted:

```js
export type ICheckboxProps = {
  checked?: boolean
  indeterminate?: boolean
} & React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>

export const Checkbox = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, ICheckboxProps>((props, inRef) => {
  const { checked = false, ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={checked}
      ref={ref => {
        if (ref) {
          ref.indeterminate = !checked ? indeterminate! : false;
          if (inRef) {
            if (typeof inRef === "function") {
              inRef(ref)
            } else {
              inRef.current = ref // Cannot assign to 'current' because it is a read-only property.
            }
          }
        }
      }}
      {...rest}
    />
  )
})
```

Answer (score 10):

The `useImperativeHandle` hook does almost exactly the same as your second example. The assignment of `ref.current` to `inRef` is then handled internally by React, and you don't have to break the contract by changing the readonly property.

```js
export const Checkbox = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, ICheckboxProps>((props, inRef) => {
  const { checked = false, indeterminate, ...rest } = props;

  const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
  useImperativeHandle(inRef, () => ref.current!, [ref])

  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={checked}
      ref={ref}
      {...rest}
    />
  )
})
```

[In typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=22&ssc=3&pln=8&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBXAZyWQDNtCkBJcJKFGYANyQAkUA7AEwBskBfOCSgQQcAERRUGMQCgZSAB6RYcGAE8wSOJQDCACyRoA1gCMICgArCwBOAF5cMuHDQHjSTgH4AXHDMReDic4YC4kGFoQUPokHz8IANR2GQEAMkQpGAA6SnYwPBgWABUAWQAZAEEYGChgEwKkAgAeYvLc-JgAUV4QJHYYAD45RWV4NAh2Anh9Q1Nzewz0bJJoAHcUKE5SFtKy9oLupF7%207F03OctrAgGAChuwK%20xQ0gBKewHHZ3HJ%20BwXc48CxIKG4RCeYQiUCi7Bi2Cy8MkUzgAgcDwgNgA3HIvhMkZISAsKNtWns8gcen1Bjd2HhuNwXsEKNRNHQGMw2FxeDdnkgyHAbm87B98Vk0HgoJJ%20gBCBnBSQwcXsfnBZxNUIdFXOVQaJB2MSuWZmBSyLVag3uTh2HDmowePia5z4q34%202m5w4eFZREwV1agD0Q2cDL4LyAA)

I would like to make a comment on the non-null assertion on `ref.current`. As far as I can tell, refs for children are resolved before refs for parents, but the only related statement in the documentation I could find is calling `inputRef.current.focus()` without a null guard in the [documentation of `useImperativeHandle`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)

Comment: what does exclamation marks mean after ref.current ?

Comment: @N.SH [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#:~:text=Non%2Dnull%20assertion%20operator&text=post%2Dfix%20expression%20operator%20may,with%20null%20and%20undefined%20excluded.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do anything you want with the forwarded ref, including setting its current value:

```
const Checkbox = React.forwardRef(({ checked = false, indeterminate, ...rest }, forwardedRef) => (
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={checked}
    ref={(inputElement) => {
      if (inputElement) {
        inputElement.indeterminate = !checked && indeterminate
      }

      if (forwardedRef) {
        if(typeof(forwardedRef) === "function") {
          forwardedRef(inputElement)
      } else {
        forwardedRef.current = inputElement
      }
    }
    {...rest}
  />
))
```

Comment: This handles 95% of cases, but it's *theoretically* possible that the forwarded ref is *also* a callback ref. I guess in that case I could do `if (forwardedRef && typeof(forwardedRef) === "function") forwardedRef(inputElement)`?

Comment: However, I also have this issue with it: "Cannot assign to 'current' because it is a read-only property."

Comment: Ah right, I forgot about that. Yes indeed, I don't see a way around that. React must do something similar since they accept refs and callback refs. Editing the answer for completeness.

About TypeScript complaining, I never used TypeScript, but there seems to be 2 object types for refs: This issue explains it well https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31065 You might want to use the non readonly version.

Comment: The edit queue for this question is full. I'm guessing there are quite a few users trying to point out that `typeof(forwardedRef) !== "function"` needs to be changed to `typeof(forwardedRef) == "function"` in order to work (take out the exclamation mark).

Comment: @JoshuaCWebDeveloper Made the edit